# Creating pygal.Bar chart from Pandas series value counts?

Tags: python, pandas, pygal

I'm trying to build a pygal bar chart from a pandas DataFrame series onto which `.value_counts()` is applied e.g. without having to split the series into multiple columns and add those columns individually, as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.pygal.org/en/latest/documentation/types/bar.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261588/create-pygal-graph-from-pandas-dataframe).

```
import pandas as pd
import pygal

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'categorical': ['foo','foo','bar','foo','bar','too']})

series = df.categorical.value_counts()
series
> foo    3
  bar    2
  too    1
```

Ideally the result looks like the plot in the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698558/pygal-bar-chart-says-no-data). Can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question you linked doesn't have a picture in the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you were aiming for:

[image: Pygal bar chart created from a Pandas series]

Pygal doesn't isn't able to plot Pandas objects directly, but you can take advantage of the attributes of the `Series` object returned by `value_counts` to set the x labels of a chart and add the counts as a series of data.

The chart above was created with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pygal

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'categorical': ['foo','foo','bar','foo','bar','too']})
series = df.categorical.value_counts()

chart = pygal.Bar(width=400, height=300)
chart.x_labels = series.index
chart.add("Count", series.values)

chart.render_to_png("bar.png")  # Or any other output option.
```